# Symbol timing recovery algorithms

Tags: estimation, decimation, synchronization

I am trying to implement the symbol timing recovery loop and for that I have chosen two algorithm to compare my results one is feedforward and Gardner TED. One thing that is confusing me is smoothing of error after finding timing error and finding the right sampler.

Should I use the sampler after matched filter or before matched filter?
how the new timing is computed from the timing error?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context, maybe a system block diagram? To me, it's unclear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to implement Timing recovery using Gardner's TED which contains, Interpolator followed by TED algorithm. The Timing error computed is fed to loop filter and then followed by VCO. the output of VCO is gives the timing instants to interpolator. I have problems in understanding the process involved after finding TED. This question might be redundant or too simple. I have problems in understanding particularly VCO and how to finding the next sampling instants.

Comment: Without a block diagram, code, or graphs it's hard to help. The timing error is error of the sampling time, and you sample at the output of the matched filter.